# Add and Retrieve MySql Database data using primary key through arraylist JAVA

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, arraylist

I have a mysql table like this

```
create table students(id varchar(20),
name varchar(20),
address varchar(255)
primary key(id));
```

I want to display data for each student using his unique id in jsp.I have tried like this

```
ArrayList<Object> student = new ArrayList<Object>();

      try {
           DB_Conn con = new DB_Conn();
           Connection c = con.getConnection();
           Statement statement = c.createStatement() ;
           ResultSet resultset = statement.executeQuery("select * from students");
           while(resultset.next()){
               student.add(resultset.getString(1));
               student.add(resultset.getString(2));
               student.add(resultset.getString(3));
           } 
        } catch (SQLException e){
              System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }  
        return student;
```

Now i want to display  name and address of each student using their unique id. How to diplay like that . How can i retrieve specific variable data from arraylist.

Comment: Instead of directly inserting different values into arraylist, create object of student and object in Arraylist and then retrive object of student.

Answer (score 0):

Try Making `Student` Class having `id`,`name`,`address` as it's attribute , then instead of adding attributes in ArrayList, you should add the Student Object

```
ArrayList<Student> studentList=new ArrayList<Student>();
String id=resultset.getString(1);
String name=resultset.getString(2);
String address=resultset.getString(3);
Student st=new Student(id,name.address);
studentList.add(st);
```

To display the Same in JSP , you can use

```
<c:forEach var="i" items="${studentList}>
   ${i.name}<br>${i.id}<br>${i.address}
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple way to do this-most common is

**use two different Arraylist to store the name & address of student**

```
ArrayList<Object> nameList= new ArrayList<Object>();
ArrayList<Object> addressList= new ArrayList<Object>();
```

and use-

```
nameList.add(resultset.getString(2));
addressList.add(resultset.getString(3));
```

at particuler value int of i `nameList.get(i)` & `addressList.get(i)` will give you result of specific student.